# React Full calendar Change View API

Tags: node.js, reactjs, fullcalendar

Im working on a full calendar app in react. My goal is to click a day tile in 'DayGridMonth' view and have it switch to that day in the 'DayGridDay' view.

I've used the dateClick function to trigger the event but there is no access to the changeView API. I've also tried creating a reference within my component to the actual full calendar object but I cant find it there either.

Thank you

Code snippet:

```
import React from 'react';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/react';

//css calendar compoonents
import '@fullcalendar/core/main.css';
import '@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css';
import './styles.css';

export default class Calendar extends React.Component {

  calendarRef = React.createRef();

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <FullCalendar
          timeZone='UTC' //since SQL dates dont have timezones
          defaultView='dayGridMonth'
          header={{
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'dayGridMonth,dayGridWeek,dayGridDay',
          }}

          dateClick={this.handleDateClick}
          plugins={[dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
          dayRender={this.assignLogoMonth}
          ref={this.calendarRef}
        />
      </>
    );
  }

  handleDateClick = dateClickInfo => {
  //would like this to take me to dayGridDay view of this day
    console.log(this.calendarRef.current.getApi());
  };    
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you read https://fullcalendar.io/docs/react, specifically the part entitled "Accessing Fullcalendar's API"?

Comment: That's assuming you're actually using Fullcalendar's react component (which if you're not, it would make sense to do so)

Comment: I've tried using the method described in that document, but there is no getAPI() method in the returned object. I've added code to make the issue more clear, thank you for responding!

Comment: Sorry I don't see where in the code you tried to call the getApi method? What result did you get when you tried? You've logged the calendarRef object to the console, I can see that. And you're saying there's no getApi method there. Well, that's probably true because as per the documentation, it's called `getApi` not `getAPI`, and more importantly the method is inside the "current" sub-property of the calendarRef object. e.g. it suggests to use it like this: `this.calendarRef.current.getApi()`.

Comment: Sorry I did not leave that in the code snippet. The object returned by getApi() does not have the api method I'm looking for, change::view, https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-changeView which is the main problem I have.

Comment: my result is a very large calendar object, but no sign of the change::view Api

Comment: it's called `changeView` not change::view. Does that help? It should be simple to use: e.g. `let calendarApi = this.calendarComponentRef.current.getApi();
    calendarApi.changeView("timeGridDay");` Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/fullcalendar-v4-react-bnkkr?file=/src/DemoApp.jsx . (I'm not a React developer at all but I made a small change to the demo provided in the fullCalendar docs, and it seems easy enough to use the API object, as you can see you can click the "go to day view" button, which uses the API to change the view using `changeView`)

Comment: I found the solution, I'm not sure why it was giving me such an issue. I'll post it below, thanks for your help!

Comment: I am using fullcalendar react version 5.10 in my app and I am getting error on this line `ref={calendarComponentRef}` that **no overload matches this call**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Event though the changeView attribute is not in the returned createRef object you can still access the function. I think I just misunderstood what the react createRef function really did.

The following code will cause your calendar to link into the day view.

```
  handleDateClick = dateClickInfo => {
    this.calendarRef.current
        .getApi()
        .changeView('dayGridDay', dateClickInfo.date)
  };
```

Thanks to ADyson for helping me sort this out!

Comment: For version 5 of Full calendar please use dateClickInfo.start in the code above.